# How to build micro frontend with Quasar?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, micro-frontend

I am trying to apply the concept of micro frontend and microservice into my current project.
For frontend development, I am using https://quasar.dev/ and backend https://www.scala-lang.org/.
I have the following scenario:

[image]

I have 3 microservices and each of them has their own frontend, which is running inside NGINX container. Also every microservice has their own backend and it is written in Scala.

Now, what I am trying to achieve is the following:

[image]

- I enter the url example.io/app1, then the **microservice1** should get called. The content(rectangle with a blue border) of App Shell should show the quasar app from the **microservice1**.
- Then I change the url to example.io/app2. Then the **microservice2** should get called and the content(rectangle with a blue border) of App Shell should show the quasar app from the **microservice2**.

The App Shell acts like a container, in which another app is running inside. Martin Fowler wrote a wonderful article about [micro frontend](https://martinfowler.com/articles/micro-frontends.html).

The question is, how to create an App Shell as a main layout for frontend app?

Comment: Did you ever figure anything out? I have a pretty large quasar 1 app that i want to turn in to micro services.
I was thinking it would be cool as an app-extension.